# Why do I get this error i app file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function env() in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\config\app.php on line 16
```

I got this answer If you have not renamed the `.env.example` file to `.env`, you should do that now. If the application key is not set, your user sessions and other encrypted data will not be secure!

Comment: Isn't it self-explanatory?

Answer (score 0):

In this folder [C:\xampp\htdocs\larave] you should have a '.env' file.

Whenever the `env()` function is called it looks for a variable in your .env file.

For example in app.php, this line means that the variable 'debug' will be set to the APP_DEBUG variable .env

`'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),`

Otherwise, it will default to false.

This will look like this in your .env file:
`APP_DEBUG=true`

There is more detail in the Laravel docs here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation#environment-configuration

Answer (score 0):

add controller

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;